# R: drawing a polar heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, polar-coordinates

This question builds off of this polar histogram function whose value and example I provide here for completeness, since the original site does not have this link.

```
#' polarHistogram builds many  histogram and arranges them around a circle to save space.
#' C. Ladroue, after Kettunen, J. et al. Genome-wide association study identifies multiple loci influencing human serum metabolite levels. Nat Genet advance online publication (2012). URL http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/ng.1073.
#' CC licence: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/ 
#' Attribution - You must attribute the work in the manner specified by the author or licensor (but not in any way that suggests that they endorse you or your use of the work).
#' Noncommercial - You may not use this work for commercial purposes.
#' Share Alike - If you alter, transform, or build upon this work, you may distribute the resulting work only under the same or similar license to this one. 
#'
#' v. 21022012
#'
#' The data frame is expected to have at least four columns: family, item, score and value. 
#' The three first columns are categorical variables, the fourth column contains non-negative values.
#' See testPolarHistogram.R for an example.
#' Each bar represents the proportion of scores for one item. Items can be grouped by families.
#' The resulting graph can be busy and might be better off saved as a pdf, with ggsave("myGraph.pdf").
#'
#' @author Christophe Ladroue
#' @param df a data frame containing the data
#' @param binSize width of the bin. Should probably be left as 1, as other parameters are relative to it.
#' @param spaceItem space between bins
#' @param spaceFamily space between families
#' @param innerRadius radius of inner circle
#' @param outerRadius radius of outer circle. Should probably be left as 1, as other parameters are relative to it.
#' @param guides a vector with percentages to use for the white guide lines
#' @param alphaStart offset from 12 o'clock in radians
#' @param circleProportion proportion of the circle to cover
#' @param direction whether the increasing count goes from or to the centre.
#' @param familyLabels logical. Whether to show family names
#' @return a ggplot object
#' @export
#' @examples
#' See testPolarHistogram.R

polarHistogram<-function(
                         df,
                         binSize=1,
                         spaceItem=0.2,
                         spaceFamily=1.2,
                         innerRadius=0.3,
                         outerRadius=1,
                         guides=c(10,20,40,80),
                         alphaStart=-0.3,
                         circleProportion=0.8,
                         direction="inwards",
                         familyLabels=FALSE){

    require(plyr)
    require(ggplot2)
    ## ordering
    df<-arrange(df,family,item,score)
    
    ## summing up to one
    ## TO DO: replace NA by 0 because cumsum doesn't ignore NA's.
    df<-ddply(df,.(family,item),transform,value=cumsum(value/(sum(value))))
    
    ## getting previous value
    df<-ddply(df,.(family,item),transform,previous=c(0,head(value,length(value)-1)))
    
    ## family and item indices. There must be a better way to do this
    df2<-ddply(df,.(family,item),summarise,indexItem=1)
    df2$indexItem<-cumsum(df2$indexItem)
    df3<-ddply(df,.(family),summarise,indexFamily=1)
    df3$indexFamily<-cumsum(df3$indexFamily)
    
    df<-merge(df,df2,by=c("family",'item'))
    df<-merge(df,df3,by="family")
    
    df<-arrange(df,family,item,score)
    
    ## define the bins
    ## linear projection  
    affine<-switch(direction,
                   'inwards'= function(y) (outerRadius-innerRadius)*y+innerRadius,
                   'outwards'=function(y) (outerRadius-innerRadius)*(1-y)+innerRadius,
                   stop(paste("Unknown direction")))
    
    df<-within(df,{
        xmin<-(indexItem-1)*binSize+(indexItem-1)*spaceItem+(indexFamily-1)*(spaceFamily-spaceItem)
        xmax<-xmin+binSize
        ymin<-affine(1-previous)
        ymax<-affine(1-value)
    }
    )
    
    ## build the guides
    guidesDF<-data.frame(
        xmin=rep(df$xmin,length(guides)),
        y=rep(1-guides/100,1,each=nrow(df)))
    
    guidesDF<-within(guidesDF,{
        xend<-xmin+binSize
        y<-affine(y)
    })
    
    
    ## Building the ggplot object
    
    totalLength<-tail(df$xmin+binSize+spaceFamily,1)/circleProportion-0

    ## histograms
    p<-ggplot(df)+geom_rect(
                      aes(
                          xmin=xmin,
                          xmax=xmax,
                          ymin=ymin,
                          ymax=ymax,
                          fill=score)
                  )
    
    ## item labels
    readableAngle<-function(x){
        angle<-x*(-360/totalLength)-alphaStart*180/pi+90
        angle+ifelse(sign(cos(angle*pi/180))+sign(sin(angle*pi/180))==-2,180,0)
    }
    readableJustification<-function(x){
        angle<-x*(-360/totalLength)-alphaStart*180/pi+90
        ifelse(sign(cos(angle*pi/180))+sign(sin(angle*pi/180))==-2,1,0)
    }
    
    dfItemLabels<-ddply(df,.(item),summarize,xmin=xmin[1])
    dfItemLabels<-within(dfItemLabels,{
        x<-xmin+binSize/2
        angle<-readableAngle(xmin+binSize/2)
        hjust<-readableJustification(xmin+binSize/2)
    })

    p<-p+geom_text(
             aes(
                 x=x,
                 label=item,
                 angle=angle,
                 hjust=hjust),
             y=1.02,
             size=3,
             vjust=0.5,
             data=dfItemLabels)
    
    ## guides  
    p<-p+geom_segment(
             aes(
                 x=xmin,
                 xend=xend,
                 y=y,
                 yend=y),
             colour="white",
             data=guidesDF)
    
    ## label for guides
    guideLabels<-data.frame(
        x=0,
        y=affine(1-guides/100),
        label=paste(guides,"% ",sep='')
    )
    
    p<-p+geom_text(
             aes(x=x,y=y,label=label),
             data=guideLabels,
             angle=-alphaStart*180/pi,
             hjust=1,
             size=4)
    
    ## family labels
    if(familyLabels){
        ##     familyLabelsDF<-ddply(df,.(family),summarise,x=mean(xmin+binSize),angle=mean(xmin+binSize)*(-360/totalLength)-alphaStart*180/pi)
        familyLabelsDF<-aggregate(xmin~family,data=df,FUN=function(s) mean(s+binSize))
        familyLabelsDF<-within(familyLabelsDF,{
            x<-xmin
            angle<-xmin*(-360/totalLength)-alphaStart*180/pi
        })

        p<-p+geom_text(
                 aes(
                     x=x,
                     label=family,
                     angle=angle),
                 data=familyLabelsDF,
                 y=1.2)
    }  
    ##   ## empty background and remove guide lines, ticks and labels
    p<-p+theme(
             panel.background=element_blank(),
             axis.title.x=element_blank(),
             axis.title.y=element_blank(),
             panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
             panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
             axis.text.x=element_blank(),
             axis.text.y=element_blank(),
             axis.ticks=element_blank()
         )
    
    ## x and y limits
    p<-p+xlim(0,tail(df$xmin+binSize+spaceFamily,1)/circleProportion)
    p<-p+ylim(0,outerRadius+0.2)
    
    ## project to polar coordinates
    p<-p+coord_polar(start=alphaStart)
    
    ## nice colour scale
    p<-p+scale_fill_brewer(palette='Set1',type='qual')
    
    p
}
```

And its usage is:

```
library(reshape2)
set.seed(42)
nFamily<-20
nItemPerFamily<-sample(1:6,nFamily,replace=TRUE)
nValues<-3
randomWord<-function(n,nLetters=5)
  replicate(n,paste(sample(letters,nLetters,replace=TRUE),sep='',collapse=''))

df<-data.frame(
  family=rep(randomWord(nFamily),nItemPerFamily),
  item=randomWord(sum(nItemPerFamily),3))

df<-cbind(df,as.data.frame(matrix(runif(nrow(df)*nValues),nrow=nrow(df),ncol=nValues)))

df<-melt(df,c("family","item"),variable.name="score") # from wide to long
print(head(df))

polarHistogram(df,familyLabel=FALSE)
```

which gives us the following figure:

[image]

My question is however, somewhat different, even though the display I want is somewhat similar. I have the following dataset.

```
arr <- matrix(runif(15*30), nrow = 30)
dff <- as.data.frame(arr)
names(dff) <- paste(sample(letters), sample(letters), sep = "")[1:15]
```

As we can see, this is a matrix of proportions of each so-called Species in 30 locations. I want to display this figure. What I am wanting to do is to make a 270-degree circular plot like in the plot above, with the Species in the labels (where the 10%, 20%, 40%, 80%, etc is except that these would be regularly spaced), the 30 locations in the circular axis, and there being a radial cell which is colored proportional to the abundance using the RColorBrewer's . Any suggestions on how to do this? I tried the suggestion below, but got lost with how to place the Species.

```
library(tidyverse)

dff %>%
  mutate(Site = seq_along(`Species`)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Site, names_to = 'Species', values_to = 'Abundance') %>%
  mutate(yval = match(Species, colnames(dff))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Site, yval, fill = Abundance)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = colnames(dff)), hjust = 1.1, size = 3,
            data = data.frame(Site = 40.5, yval = 1:15, Abundance = 1)) +
  coord_polar() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-5, 15.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0.5, 40.5), breaks = 1:30) +
  scale_fill_distiller(direction = 1, limits = 0:1, labels = scales::percent) +
  theme_void(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title.x = element_text())
```

I get the error:

```
 Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `Site = seq_along(`Species 1`)`.
Caused by error in `mask$eval_all_mutate()`:
! object 'Species 1' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I tried adding Species to each of the names, but even that was not successful, and I do not like the Species hanging out everywhere in the name.

Separately, another option for the figure is to make the text on the Species actually placed in a circle with the heatmap not there where the text for the Species is, (and then of course, the angle would not be 270), but I am not sure if that would be a different question.
Let me know if my question needs more clarification.

Comment: You get the error with the solution because you should change "names(dff) <- paste(sample(letters), sample(letters), sample(letters), sep = '')[1:15]" to "names(dff) <- paste('Species', 1:15)" and keep the given solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is a polar heat map. We can do this ourselves in `ggplot` using `geom_tile` and `coord_polar`, though we need a little data reshaping first:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dff %>%
  mutate(Site = seq_along(`Species 1`)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Site, names_to = 'Species', values_to = 'Abundance') %>%
  mutate(yval = match(Species, colnames(dff))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Site, yval, fill = Abundance)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = colnames(dff)), hjust = 1.1, size = 3,
            data = data.frame(Site = 35.5, yval = 1:15, Abundance = 1)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0:30 + 0.5) +
  coord_polar() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-5, 15.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0.5, 35.5), breaks = 1:30, 
                     name = 'Breeding site') +
  scale_fill_distiller(direction = 1, limits = 0:1, labels = scales::percent) +
  theme_void(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title.x = element_text())
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but  what if I have my "Species" names as "AA", "BC", "EF", "GR", "PQ", etc? I made it to "Species 1-15" for simpicity (I thought).

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference to this code as long as the data is in the same format.

Comment: @user3236841 Try `mutate(Site = seq(nrow(.)))` in the second line instead.

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks! Btw, what do I do, if I want a plot to be greater than 270 degrees?

Comment: Sorry, one more issue. My title is really not Site, but 'Breeding Site'. Can I do the label separately? I also would like to have lines separating out each of the species, like in a grid.

Comment: @user3236841 if you want greater than 270 degrees, you need to reduce the x axis limits. Since you have 30 sites, you need an upper x axis range of 40 to get 270 degrees of the circle filled, since 30/40 is three quarters of the circle. I have shown in the example reducing this to 35, so that about 308 degrees (30/35 of a circle) are filled. You need to leave enough space for the labels, which also need to be set to the upper limit of the x axis to go in the correct position. The "spokes" you want can be added by geom_vline. See my update.

Comment: Thanks very much, this helps a lot. Btw, I want spokes, but also the concentric grid.

Comment: @user3236841 in that case add `color = 'black'` inside `geom_tile`

Comment: One more question, where is the color palette supplied? Is it the default in geom_tile?

Comment: No, I specifically added scale_fill_distiller, which by default uses the Brewer palettes (as you requested). See ?scale_fill_distiller for the different palettes you can use.

Comment: Thanks, so if I wanted non-brewer palettes(i.e. that I made), then I use scale_fill_manual, or can I still use scale_fill_distiller? I basically need to increase my number of colors (possibly using colorRampPalette).

Comment: @user3236841 in that case you would use scale_gradientn - there are loads of online resources to guide you on how to use this, including many great posts here on SO

Comment: Thank you!  replacing `scale_fill_distiller(...)` with  `scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("#FFFFFF", colorRampPalette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(name = "Blues", n = 9))(255)), limits = 0:1, labels = scales::percent)` appears to do it for me.

Comment: one more question: what if I would like the 1:30 to instead be strings[1:30] with the names of the sites in the strings, as character strings?

Comment: Use the `labels` argument of scale_x_continuous